# URLs without www all redirect to home page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What do I need to do to redirect non-www URLs to their corresponding pages with www in the URL?

For example, there's a page called `www.mysite.com/contactus`. If try to access this site via `mysite.com/contactus`, it simply redirects to `www.mysite.com`.

Basically, I'd like all `mysite.com/*` to go to `www.mysite.com/*` instead of just going to the home page. Is this an htaccess configuration? Below is what I have for the mod_rewrite. Let me know if more information is required.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please comment if you're going to down vote and suggest another forum if this is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Would the `L` flag prevent any following `RewriteCond`s to be checked?

Comment: Yes it will. `L` flag only ends current rule.

Comment: For the `RewriteRule`, is `^` sufficient? How about `^(.*)$`?

Comment: Since you're using `%{REQUEST_URI}` there is no need to make rewrite engine to match & capture URI in `$1` to avoid extra bit of processing.